# Transferring user clicked/swiped item from one listview in 1st fragment to another listview in 2nd fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-intent, listadapter

I need to know how we can move an item from a listview on 1st fragment to another listview on 2nd fragment.Below is the code for 2 fragments and the xml file which contains views for list items.
**AbsentStudentFragment.java**

**Edit:**
I have replace all the arrays with array list and I am generating data for list adapter using Arraylist with a simple POJO class.
Please check below.My question is how can I use the values I am getting from list item like name,confidence etc or the POJO I am getting of type StudentDetails and add those values to the PresentStudent arraylist in PresentStudent fragment.?

```
public class AbsentStudentFragment extends Fragment
{
ListView listForAbsentStudents;
Context context;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       final ArrayList<StudentDetails> stuAbsent= new ArrayList<>();

    stuAbsent.add(new StudentDetails("name","nameNot",R.mipmap.user));
    stuAbsent.add(new StudentDetails("81","checkName",R.mipmap.user));
    stuAbsent.add(new StudentDetails("60","3rd",R.mipmap.user));

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_absent_students, container,false);
    context=getActivity();
    listForAbsentStudents=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview_for_absent_students);
  final AdapterForAbsentList adapterForAbsentList=new    AdapterForAbsentList(context,stuAbsent);
       listForAbsentStudents.setAdapter(adapterForAbsentList);
        listForAbsentStudents.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 //what to do here.?
                //Added below code now
            StudentDetails studentDetails4;
            studentDetails4=stuAbsent.get(position);

            String temName=studentDetails4.getStudentName();
            String tempConfidence=studentDetails4.getStudentConfidence();
            int tempImage=studentDetails4.getStudentImage();
 //Now how can I add these values to presentstudent array list in PresentStudent.java fragment.?

                         //presentStudentFragment.addToPresentStudents(temName,tempConfidence,tempImage);
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),"value"+temName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
        return view;
    }
    public class AdapterForAbsentList extends BaseAdapter
    {

  public AdapterForAbsentList(Context   mContext,ArrayList<StudentDetails>absentStudents) 
{
        this.absentStudents2 = absentStudents;

this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    ArrayList<StudentDetails> absentStudents2;
    private Context mContext;



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return absentStudents2.size();;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View viewForListView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
 viewForListView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_for_absent_list,null);
            TextView txtConfidence=(TextView)viewForListView.findViewById(R.id.txtConfidence_Temp);
            TextView txtName=(TextView)viewForListView.findViewById(R.id.txtName_Temp);
            ImageView imgStudentThumbnail=(ImageView)viewForListView.findViewById(R.id.imgFile_Temp);
           txtConfidence.setText(absentStudents2.get(i).getStudentConfidence());
            txtName.setText(absentStudents2.get(i).getStudentName());
            imgStudentThumbnail.setImageResource(absentStudents2.get(i).getStudentImage());

        }
        else
        {
            viewForListView = convertView;
        }
        return viewForListView;
    }
    }
    }
```

And **PresentStudentFragment.java**
**Edited** Added the arraylist.
**How should I add values I am getting from array list on AbsentStudentFragment.java to the ArrayList listPresentStudents..?**

```
public class PresentStudentFragment extends Fragment {
ListView listForPresentStudents;
 public ArrayList<StudentDetails>listPresentStudents=new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_present_students, container, false);
    context=getActivity();
        listPresentStudents.add(new StudentDetails("80","saurabh",R.mipmap.user));
    listPresentStudents.add(new StudentDetails("60","pqr",R.mipmap.user));

    listForPresentStudents=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview_for_present_students);

 AdapterForPresentList adapterForPresentListNew=new AdapterForPresentList(context,listPresentStudents);

   listForPresentStudents.setAdapter(adapterForPresentList);
    return view;
    }
 public class AdapterForPresentList extends BaseAdapter 
 {

    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<StudentDetails>abc;


    public AdapterForPresentList(Context context,    ArrayList<StudentDetails>pqr) 
 {
        this.mContext=context;
        this.abc = pqr;
 }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return abc.size();;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        View viewForListView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            viewForListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_for_present_list, null);
            TextView txtConfidence=(TextView)viewForListView.findViewById(R.id.txtConfidence_Temp2);
            TextView txtName=(TextView)viewForListView.findViewById(R.id.txtName_Temp2);
            ImageView imgStudentThumbnail=(ImageView)viewForListView.findViewById(R.id.imgFile_Temp2);

       txtName.setText(abc.get(i).getStudentName());
            txtConfidence.setText(abc.get(i).getStudentConfidence());
              imgStudentThumbnail.setImageResource(abc.get(i).getStudentImage());


        } else
        {
            viewForListView = convertView;
        }
        return viewForListView;
    }


    }
    }
```

POJO class **StudentDetails.java**

```
 public class StudentDetails {
 String studentName,studentConfidence;
 int studentImage;

 public StudentDetails() {
 }

 public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
 }

 public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
 }

 public String getStudentConfidence() {
    return studentConfidence;
 }

 public void setStudentConfidence(String studentConfidence) {
    this.studentConfidence = studentConfidence;
 }

 public int getStudentImage() {
    return studentImage;
 }

 public void setStudentImage(int studentImage) {
    this.studentImage = studentImage;
 }

 public StudentDetails(String studentName, String studentConfidence, int studentImage) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.studentConfidence = studentConfidence;
    this.studentImage = studentImage;
 }
 }
```

And views for list items **custom_row_list**

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgFile_Temp2"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/user"
    android:padding="10dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgFile_Temp2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtConfidence_Temp2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName_Temp2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

What i need is if I swipe/clicked an item from `listForAbsentStudents` list then it should get transferred to `listForPresentStudents` list and that item should be deleted from absent student list.
How can I do this..Forget about doing swiping..it seems distant to me.. 
Please tell me what should I do on `onItemclick()` method of `listview` to achieve this.
should I use intents and/or bundle to pass extras..if so how..?
Something along the lines of `parent.getItemAt(position)`..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not getting what are you are asking..i assume that one of your Fragment contains ListView..Right? If users clicks any Item from the ListView,that Item Should be passed to another fragment..Right?

please use this in AbsentStudentFragment.java where in onItemClick(..) method

```
 PresentStudentFragment fragObj = new PresentStudentFragment();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putString("YourKey", "YourValue");
 //as many as putString() you want  
 fragObj.setArguments(args);
```

where in PresentStudentFragment.java inside your onCreateView(..) method

```
String value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: No..actually what I wanted was to pass an item from one listview to another..yes you are right that both listviews are in separate fragments...problem was in fargment communication..I did tried using 'interface and activity method' bt that didn't work too...so finally by using sqlite db in backend I made it work...thanks for your reply anyway..